# return multiple service data at the same time in augular 2?

Tags: angular

I am working on angular 4, currently using the same web service to load different data for multiple times and return all the multiple data back to the component at the same time.

```
  loadTemplate(token):  Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get("/assets/guide/"+token+"_"+type+".html").map(res =>res.text());
  }
```

how would i wrap these http service together into one function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`.combineLatest`**

```
const bothrequests= Observable.combineLatest(
  this.http.get('https://testdb1.com/.json').map((res: Response) => res.json()),
  this.http.get('https://testdb2.com/.json').map((res: Response) => res.json())
)
bothrequests.subscribe(latestValues => {

});
```